# How to load xml resources to Activity field

Tags: android, android-activity, android-xml, android-resources, android-lifecycle

What I did is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String[] types = { "s1", "s2", "s3" };
```

But I want to keep those values in `res/values/types.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="types">
            <item>s1</item>
            <item>s2</item>
            <item>s3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

So I changed to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String[] types = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types);
```

But I get exception when app starts

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

So I suppose the only solution is to load that array in `onCreate`? If so then after Activity recreation should I load it again?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, onCreate is a good place to initialize your variable. Apparently getResources() method cannot be used before activity (context) is properly initialized.

However, if you don't need a super effective code, you can simply use `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types)` when you need your array or you can create a method

```
private String[] getTypes() {
    return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to call a Context method when the Activity is not created. 
Try call it in OnCreate() :)